# Izimodal не обновляется информация в окне при использовании ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Немного предыстории: начал использовать библиотеку iziModal, все вроде бы хорошо, но вот произошел для меня не понятный случай, при вызове контента посредством ajax с различных уролов, внутри модального окна он не меняется (если осуществлять вызов при нажатии на кнопку одну вторую третью, то контент остается тот же, что и при нажатии на первую кнопку, хотя урлы разные и информация в них другая).

Как это сделано, при нажатии на кнопку через js считывается ее id и передается в скрипт передавая этот id в шаблон url адреса. Если обновить страницу и нажать например на кнопку с id 3 то в окне появится соответствующий контент для id 3, если обновить страницу еще раз и нажать например на кнопку с id 9 все так же работает, но если например нажать на кнопку с id 3 а после на кнопку с id 9 то контент останется от первоначальной нажатой кнопки (то есть свойственен id кнопки на которую нажали первой), при этом в инспекторе видно, что контент в модальном окне заменяется, но заменяется на тот же, который был при нажатии на первую кнопку (первую не по счету) вне зависимости от нажатой кнопки.

При ручном переходе между ссылками с уникальными id все работает, выводиться информация иммено под конкретный id, почему информация не обновляется в модальном окне понять не могу, буду рад если вы сможете мне помочь.
Код с php  и js ниже:

php mvc =
**Controller:**

```
function cards_this_group()
    {
        $user = user::i()->getUser();
        if($user)
        {
            $this->assign('cards', shop::get_cards_this_group($this->request[':id'], $user['id']));
            $this->_template = 'frontend/get_cards_this_group.tpl';
        }
        else
        {
            location('/shop');
        }
}
```

**Class**

```
public static function get_cards_this_group($group_id, $user_id) {
        $cards = database::i()->bought_cards('user_id = ?', $user_id)->where('card_id = ?', $group_id);
        return $cards;
}
```

**Представление (вывод простого id для теста)**

```
{% for card in cards %}
    {{ card.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Js который выводит модальное окно, а также информацию в нем через ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function open_cards_this_group(elem) {
    var card_id = elem.value;
    var url = "{{ app }}card/my_cards/id_group/" + card_id;
    // console.log(url);

    $("#modal2").iziModal({
        title: 'Тайтл',
        subtitle: 'Субтайтл',
        headerColor: '#88A0B9',
        zindex: '9999',
        padding: 5,
        onOpening: function(modal){
          modal.startLoading();
          $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: url,
              cache: false,
              async: true,
              success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                  $("#modal2 .iziModal-content").html(data);
                  modal.stopLoading();
              }
          });
        }
      });
    $("#modal2").iziModal('open');
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока не разобрался в чем причина, но после того как с:

```
var url = "{{ app }}card/my_cards/id_group/" + card_id;
```

было удалено **var**

```
url = "{{ app }}card/my_cards/id_group/" + card_id;
```

Контент начал обновляться верно.